# I accidentally encrypted my backup keys with EFS now I cannot access my backup

Tags: encryption, user-accounts, efs

I basically locked my keys in the car so to speak, I saved backup keys using manager to a usb but I somehow also encrypted my backup keys. On top of that I reinstalled windows. Now its asking for the old windows account to decrypt my backup keys...
I have a macrium backup of this drive but where do I start?

I try to access file properties and untick the box "encrypt contents" and get error "the specified file could not be decrypted."

I try to add myself and get "to add users to this file you must have access to the file and write or modify permission for it."

Comment: What you want is impossible to resolve. You not only locked your keys in your car, you put the car in shipping crate, and locked that with a lock and threw the keys in the ocean.